# Finding the Infimum of a set $\{\,x+x^{-1}\,|\,x\in \mathbb{R}, x>0\,\}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find the infimum of the set $\{\,x+x^{-1}\,|\,x\in \mathbb{R}, x>0\,\}$.My first approach would be to take the derivative of the function and solve for where it is equal to $0$ and then determine whether that critical point is a max or a minimum value, but I don't think that is the appropriate approach to these problems. Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $x+x^{-1} = 2+(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x^{-1}})^2$. Also, taking derivative and analyzing the zeros is also fine too.

Comment: Your idea sounds like a great solution. If you can find a minimum value, and determine that the function decreases towards it and increases away from it, then you're done.

Answer (score 4):

for $x>0$, by the simple inequality $a+b\geq2\sqrt{ab}$,you get
$$
x+1/x\geq 2
$$
and 2 is attainable when $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$y=x+\frac 1x\iff x^2-xy+1=0$

This is $x^2-sx+p=0$ with $s=y$ and $p=1$.

The minimum of this parabola is reached in the middle of the two roots thus for $x=\dfrac s2=\dfrac y2$

This leads to $y=\dfrac y2+\dfrac 2y\iff y^2=4$ and since $y>0$ then $y_{min}=2$.

Answer (score 0):

AM-GM:

$x\gt 0.$

$ x+1/x \ge 2 \sqrt{x(1/x)} =2$.

$x=1$ gives the maximum $ =2$.